# I don't have KVM even though virtualization is enabled in BIOS

Tags: centos7, rhel7

My name is Philippe and I have a problem I thought you could help me with. When I try to create a new virtual machine in Virtual Machine Manager I get the following error:
“Warning: KVM is not available. This may mean the KVM package is not installed, or the KVM kernel modules are not loaded. Your virtual machines may perform poorly.”
when I run: # lsmod | grep kvm
all I get is: kvm 525259 0
I have a AMD A10-4600M APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics processor.
I downloaded all the necessary virtualization packages, I started libvirtd and enabled it as well.
I do not know what I’m not doing or what I’m doing wrong, my cpu supports virtualization and I made sure it is enabled in the BIOS but I do not know what kind of cpu RHEL7 requires for kvm or what I need to do to get this cpu to work with KVM.
I also ran the egrep ‘(vmx|svm)’ /proc/cpuinfo and received no output.
Please help me, I’m really trying to learn RedHat and pass my certifications but don’t want to keep getting frustrated.
Thank you, I appreciate your help!
Philippe

PS: I'm using CentOS7 in VirtualBox.

Comment: Don't run it in VirtualBox.

Comment: Where should I run it ?

Comment: On a physical machine.

Comment: Is there not another way using virtualization ?

Comment: You can't nest virtualization within VirtualBox. This is hairy at best in other situations, and as far as my experience goes always performs like complete trash. Put it on baremetal. Not many consumer machines lack support for virtualization extensions.

Answer (score 2):

VirtualBox doesn't support nested virtualization.  As a result your CentOS guest doesn't see hardware support for virtualization and kvm won't load.

You need to either run a different virtualization platform on your current host OS that **does** support nested virtualization or choose a different host OS and run the current OS as a guest (ex: set up CentOS as the host).